# Is it possible that two displacement sensors value( one is digital input and the other is analog) express simultaneously in a vi?

Tags: labview

I tried to express two displacement values in one waveform chart.

I have two displacement sensors, one is a digital input sensor and the other is analog input sensor.
I have to see those values in one waveform chart simultaneously.

In my attempts, two VIs of each instruments were combined into one VI. I found the error that when I ran the VI, only one VI would report values and not both simultaneously.

By any chance, is there a way to run it at the same time and see the values on one graph?

Comment: Could you post your code here? Because now it is not possible to help you without seen what is actually happening.

Comment: Please name the sensors and add the code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a few scenarios that might help solve your issue.

1. Plot multiple doubles on a chart: bundle them together and put the resulting cluster into a chart.
   [bundled doubles on a chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt1ie.png)
2. Two VIs measuring a double and plotting those results.
   [bundled subvi outputs to a chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OD4v.png)

You could similarly plot boolean values (your digital input sensor) by using the boolean to 0,1 VI first (converts the T/F to 1/0 respectively) and that can be bundled as above.

(These are the most direct/easiest ways of doing this; you have a number generator and you bundle the numbers to a graph).

Of course, I can imagine that your question might actually be about how to share values from parallel-running subVIs. If that's the case, say so and this answer can be edited to point you in the right direction.